# Compile a Scala library to JavaScript

Tags: node.js, scala.js

I want to use the `expressions` subproject from [this project](https://github.com/opencypher/front-end) in my TypeScript node.js project. I learned about Scala.js and its ability to compile Scala to javascript. I tried to follow the guide to compile the code to javascript, but I got stuck. [The tutorial](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/building.html) seems to imply that you can only build applications, not libraries.

The only way to expose the libraries' classes I can think of right now is to write a main function that would do the equivalent of `module.exports = { ClassName: ScalaClassName }`, but I've never written any Scala. Would this approach even work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit JavaScript modules with Scala.js. See [Emitting a JavaScript module](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/module.html). You probably need to add some `@JSExportTopLevel` to determine what will be part of the module, which probably means adding those annotations to the original library if it doesn't yet have them.